# How to submit info for Current User in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

In a Laravel project, I created a form using jQuery Ajax for a user to answer a few questions.

The problem is that I don't know how to associate the current user with this form. If I submit the form it will create a new user.

Form and script:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <p id="message"></p>
  <input placeholder="Name" id="full_name" name="full_name">
  <p class="name_error_text"></p>
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="option" value="1">
  <label for="1">1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="option" value="2">
  <label for="2">2</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="3" name="option" value="3">
  <label for="3">3</label><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  //Submit Data
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var full_name = $("#full_name").val();
    var option = $('input[name="option"]:checked').val();
    var url = '{{ url('
    addoption ') }}';

    if (full_name.length < 1) {
      check_name();
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          full_name: full_name,
          option: option
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $("#success").html(response.message)
        },
      });
    }
  });

});
```

`UserController`:

```
public function Store(Request $request)
    {


        \DB::table('users')->insert([
            'full_name' => $request->full_name,
            'option' => $request->option,
        ]);

        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Your data has been saved.'
            ]
     );
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/addoption', 'UserController@Store')->name('option.store');
```

Comment: Is the user a logged in user?

Comment: yes, it's a user that already has an account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert method is used to create new rows of data, and that's not what you are looking for.

What you need to do in the store method is first look for the user using:

```
$user = User::where('id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
```

Then you will have your user in the $user variable, and you can change the 'option' value associated to said user.

```
$user->option = $request->option;
$user->full_name = $request->full_name;
$user->save();

return response()->json('success');
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on where to add this?

Comment: in your Store function